# JS как удалить первый дочерний элемент в HTML(без id)

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть select с дочерними элементами option. Так как селект заполняется через массив из скрипта, то у опшинов нет id. В определенном условии(не связанном с вопросом) мне надо удалять первый опшион. Нагуглил removeChild, но как я понял - можно удалить только элемент с id

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('select option')[0].remove()  Естественно, если селект не один на странице, обращайтесь к нему по id

Comment: Или `document.getElementById('select-id').remove(0)`